# How to create own maintenance subplan in SQL server 2005 (or) 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to create own maintenance subplan in SQL server 2005 (or) 2008 ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/66819/creating-a-sql-server-maintenance-plan-without-the-wizard

Answer (score 1):

Open Management Studio. Connect to the SQL Server instance. In the Object Explorer pane, go to Management and you should see Maintenance Plans in there. Right click and you should find a wizard to make a new one.

Comment: I get the custom designed (inbuilt) or predifined plans, but I want to build my own plan ..I have my own script and I would like to schedule it . How do I do it ?

Comment: A maintenance plan is really just an SSIS package. You can schedule almost anything by going into SQL Agent and making a job there. The steps can be T-SQL, or SSIS package, PowerShell script, and more.